# VS Code Python installation and Python Interpreter not recognized (Anaconda)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda

I am getting this message on the VS Code that "Python is not installed. Please download and install python before using the extension." There is also the "Select Python Interpreter" on the bottom left hand side of VS Code. 
P.s: I installed Python through Anaconda

[Select Python Interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTHK5.png) 
[Proof that path is correct for python.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61eVz.png) 
I do have Python and Python extension installed which works within the VS Code terminal. 
[Working Python in VS Code Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKzjD.png)

Thank you in advance for your help!.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is click on `enter an interpreter path` and then click `Find` and select the `python.exe` file manually. that will create a `.vscode` folder with the `settings.json` file.
and as the `conda` environment (base) is active, you can just write `python3 main.py` to run the file.

Comment: Thank you for this workaround! But this isnt exactly a solution since I cant press f5 to run my code in VS Code

Comment: @Sheen pressing f5 actually runs the code in debug mode. You can press right mouse button and select "Run file in terminal" to run it, or you can press "ctrl + ` (backtick button)" to bring up the terminal and press the upper arrow to bring back the last command, which in this case is "python3 main.py". You don't have to write it everytime.